# Xcode 5.1.1 not symbolicating Framework lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

An application we wrote was crashing randomly on a customer's iPad Air that has iOS 7.1.1. Users running the app on other iPad types are not experiencing the problem. The customer sent us the crash logs by extracting them using iTunes and we found around 21 crashes all due to the following :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Triggered by Thread:  9

Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a00706b 0x39fbd000 + 303211
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a007001 0x39fbd000 + 303105
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3a07dd21 0x3a07b000 + 11553
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39aa83a5 0x39a9e000 + 41893
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39ab0b67 0x39a9e000 + 76647
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2edfc181 0x2edf7000 + 20865
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee085b1 0x2edf7000 + 71089
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39ab0b67 0x39a9e000 + 76647
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39ab10cf 0x39a9e000 + 78031
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39ab1b49 0x39a9e000 + 80713
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bc6cf 0x3a0bb000 + 5839
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bc44f 0x3a0bb000 + 5199
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bd1b5 0x3a0bb000 + 8629
13  Foundation                      0x2f8086ff 0x2f7e7000 + 136959
14  Foundation                      0x2f8b4a29 0x2f7e7000 + 842281
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bd957 0x3a0bb000 + 10583
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bd8c7 0x3a0bb000 + 10439
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a0bbae4 0x3a0bb000 + 2788
```

The problem is that Xcode 5.1.1 is symbolicating correctly the crash log statements that lie in our application, but it is failing to symbolicate statements from the framework, hence we are not able to see why this thread is crashing.

Help much appreciated.

Update : The question that this has been marked a duplicate of solves the problem where the dSYM file is not properly loaded and the crash log is not showing the code in the application. I am able to see the statements in the app just fine since I have loaded the dSYM successfully and even checked the validity of the dSYM by cross referencing the UUIDs. My problem is that the framework statements (The code related to iOS SDK itself) are not getting symbolicated. I don't see where any answer in that question tackles that. Here is another thread that shows the application statements correctly symbolicated :

```
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a056544 0x3a043000 + 79172
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39fc7745 0x39fbd000 + 42821
2   Foundation                      0x2f8b411d 0x2f7e7000 + 839965
3   MyAppName                   0x00255477 -[xxxx dismissView] (xxx.m:436)
4   MyAppName                   0x00259447 -[xxxx goToSessionSummaryView] (xxx.m:1459)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2eecf450 0x2edf7000 + 885840
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee199a3 0x2edf7000 + 141731
7   MyAppName                   0x001b6523 -[GTMHTTPFetcher invokeFetchCallback:target:data:error:] (GTMHTTPFetcher.m:878)
8   MyAppName                   0x001b643b -[GTMHTTPFetcher invokeFetchCallbacksWithData:error:] (GTMHTTPFetcher.m:852)
9   MyAppName                   0x001b6db5 -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] (GTMHTTPFetcher.m:1087)
10  Foundation                      0x2f80b245 0x2f7e7000 + 148037
11  Foundation                      0x2f80b185 0x2f7e7000 + 147845
12  Foundation                      0x2f80b0a1 0x2f7e7000 + 147617
13  CFNetwork                       0x2eb31295 0x2ea87000 + 696981
14  CFNetwork                       0x2eb2fe99 0x2ea87000 + 691865
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2edff197 0x2edf7000 + 33175
16  CFNetwork                       0x2eac7997 0x2ea87000 + 264599
17  CFNetwork                       0x2eac7857 0x2ea87000 + 264279
18  CFNetwork                       0x2eac76e5 0x2ea87000 + 263909
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee96fed 0x2edf7000 + 655341
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee964b3 0x2edf7000 + 652467
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee94ca3 0x2edf7000 + 646307
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2edff765 0x2edf7000 + 34661
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2edff547 0x2edf7000 + 34119
24  GraphicsServices                0x33d366cf 0x33d2d000 + 38607
25  UIKit                           0x3175e88d 0x316f0000 + 452749
26  MyAppName                   0x00108a63 main (main.m:15)
27  MyAppName                   0x000fbe14 start + 36
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit symbols for iOS 7.1.1 on your Mac? You'll get them by connection an 64bit iOS device running iOS 7.1.1 to that Mac.

Comment: @mjouni did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same problem on Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

Kerni's comment was the answer :

"Do you have the 64 bit symbols for iOS 7.1.1 on your Mac? You'll get them by connection an 64bit iOS device running iOS 7.1.1 to that Mac. – Kerni"

I plugged in an iPhone 5s with 7.1.1 and was able to extract the symbols needed to fully symbolicate the crash logs.

Thanks!